# Data not loading in grid (This error is occurring inconsistently)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, sql-server-2008, iis-7

While loading data in grid in production server I found following script Error on Page left bottom corner *(This error is occurring only on production server, in local server its working fine)*
 **This error is occurring inconsistently**

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; BTRS123646; Embedded Web Browser from: http://bsalsa.com/; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Tue, 9 Oct 2012 12:11:23 UTC

Message: **Unterminated string constant**
Line: **111115201**
Char: 187
Code: 0

URI:   XYXZ/MYApp/MyPage.aspx

following is the code for binding data in grid

```
 try
            {
                conGetPost.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStr"].ConnectionString;
                conGetPost.Open();
                SqlCommand cmdGetPost = new SqlCommand();
                cmdGetPost.CommandTimeout = 999999999;
                cmdGetPost.Connection = conGetPost;
                cmdGetPost.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmdGetPost.CommandText = "MySP";
                if (wdpfrom.Value.ToString() == "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM" || wdpTo.Value.ToString() == "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM")
                {
                    ShowMessage("Please select proper Date range");
                    wdgPost.DataSource = "";
                    wdgPost.DataBind();
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    cmdGetPost.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateFrom", wdpfrom.Value);
                    cmdGetPost.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateTo", Convert.ToDateTime(wdpTo.Value.ToString()).Add(new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59)));
                }
                cmdGetPost.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
                SqlDataAdapter daGetPost = new SqlDataAdapter();
                daGetPost.SelectCommand = cmdGetPost;
                daGetPost.Fill(dsGetPost);
                if (dsGetPost.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (dsGetPost.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 750)
                    {
                        ShowMessage("Maximum record found please reduce date range");
                        wdgPost.DataSource = "";
                        wdgPost.DataBind();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                wdgPost.ClearDataSource();
                wdgPost.DataSource = dsGetPost;
                wdgPost.DataBind();
                if (dsGetPost.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    ShowMessage("No records found");
                }
                Session["dsGetPost"] = dsGetPost;
            }
catch( Exception ex)
            {

                return;
            }
finally
            {
                if (conGetPost != null)
                {
                    conGetPost.Close();
                    conGetPost = null;
                }
            }
```

How to know the line no in my C# code?
How to fix it? Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Try add a BindingSource in between, like this: Control.DataSource = new BindingSource(source, "");

Comment: Thanx for reply but BindingSource Class comes under (System.Windows.Forms) namespace . Its a ASP.NET application, So it can't be done.

Comment: Could it be, that production server run in release mode and something is getting garbage collected too soon??

I don't know what type dsGetPost return, but I don't think you should set datasource to an empty string, instead you should clear the list in dsGetPost (Count = 0) and set the datasource with it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I finally solved it.

How I tracked it?
Enabling script debugging and used fiddler 2 tool and found whats going wrong. I found some error was thrown at date parsing.

What I did to solve?
I wrote a method for datetime conversion as

```
public static bool ValidateDate(string txtDate, string sDateFormat, ref string sErrMsg, ref DateTime dtDate)
        {
            if (txtDate == "")
            {
                sErrMsg = "Please Enter Date";
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo dateInfo = new System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo();
                dateInfo.ShortDatePattern = sDateFormat;

                try
                {
                    dtDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate, dateInfo);
                    return true;
                }
                catch
                {
                    sErrMsg = "Please Enter Date In Correct Format";
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

then I used as

```
string errMsg = string.Empty;
                Boolean IsFromDateValid = false;
                DateTime fromDate = new DateTime();
                IsFromDateValid = ValidateDate(wdpfrom.Text.Trim(), "dd/MM/yyyy", ref errMsg, ref fromDate);
                if (IsFromDateValid == false)
                {
                    ShowMessage(errMsg);
                    return;
                }
                Boolean IsToDateValid = false;
                DateTime toDate = new DateTime();
                IsToDateValid = ValidateDate(wdpTo.Text.Trim(), "dd/MM/yyyy", ref errMsg, ref toDate);
                if (IsToDateValid == false)
                {
                    ShowMessage(errMsg);
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59);
                    toDate = toDate.Add(ts);
                }
```

and finally passed parameter to SP as

```
 cmdGetPost.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateFrom", fromDate);
 cmdGetPost.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateTo", toDate);
```